# Vue JS how to delete object based on array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vue-component

I have an array of objects like:

```
types: [
{
 id: 1,
 name: "Hello"
},
{
 id: 2,
 name: "World"
},
{
 id: 3,
 name: "Jon Doe"
}
]
```

And I also have a simple array like this:

```
selected_types = [1, 2]
```

The desired result should filter the **"types"** array and exclude all the ids that are present in the **"selected_types"** array, like below:

```
final_types: [
{
 id: 3,
 name: "Jon Doe"
}
]
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to achieve this, but below is my attempt:

```
   this.types.filter(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.selected_types.length; i++) {
          if (obj.id !== selected_types[i]) {
            final_types.push(attribute);
          }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `this.types.filter(({id}) => !this.selected_types.includes(id))`:

```js
let types = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "World"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Jon Doe"
  }
]

let selected_types = [1, 2];
let resArr = types.filter(({id}) => !selected_types.includes(id));
console.log(resArr);
```

Comment: Don't know if it would be clear for author. I would recommend to add that `({id})` is the same as `let id = obj.id`.

Answer (score 0):

**You can achieve Javascript's native method filter, which finally returns a new object**

```
let types = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Hello"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "World"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Jon Doe"
  }
]

let selected_types = [1, 2];

types = types.filter(obj => {
  if (selected_types.indexOf(obj.id) === -1) {
     return obj
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the array types can get you what you want.

```
result = types.filter(el => !selected_types.includes(el.id))
```